# 'expo' command not found

Tags: 20.04

i have installed node v10.19.0 and run

> npm install expo-cli --global

but when try to run expo commands like

> expo init projectname

it's showing error like below in my ubuntu.

```
Command 'expo' not found, did you mean:

  command 'exo' from snap exoscale-cli (v1.19.0)
  command 'expn' from deb sendmail-base (8.15.2-18)
  command 'expr' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, I found out that `expo-cli` is installed already under this path `/home/$USER/.npm-global/bin` so all need to be done is to add it to the default path:

`export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.npm-global/bin"`

permanently add it to path:
`gedit gedit ~/.profile`

Then add this line at the end:

`export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.npm-global/bin"`

to get the path effected just run this command in every terminal that you wanna use: `source ~/.profile` or just log out and login again.

This worked for me.